# How to display columns depending on the date selected [From and To] in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

|Jan_2016|Feb_2016|Mar_2016|Apr_2016|May_2016|June_2016|July_2016|Aug_2016|Sept_2016|Oct_2016|Nov_2016|Dec_2016|

"From" and "To" filter are there in which we have to select dates. Depending upon the values selected, we have to select columns dynamically which lies between selected date filters.

These are different columns. I have to display columns depending on the date selected in From and To datepicker in rails.

eg: Suppose "From:=>Jan_2016" and "To=>June_2016" then we have to dsplay all columns between these two dates[like => |Jan_2016|Feb_2016|Mar_2016|Apr_2016|May_2016|June_2016|].

Thanks.

Comment: what actually you want to do? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It is not the best possible solution but it may work.

```
   start_date = params[:to]
   end_date = params[:from]
   columns = Model.column_names
   # For date filters
   start_date_index = columns.index(start_date)
   end_date_index = columns.index(end_date)
   result = columns[start_date_index..end_date_index]
```

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution

```
    current_date = from.to_date
    result = []
    while ( current_date <= to.to_date )
      result << current_date.strftime("%b_%Y") 
      current_date = current_date.next_month
    end
```

result contains the columns you have to display

Comment: Thanks for answering . Your answer was helpful in finding solution